# Setting the size of a UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController subclass to control a UIView that I want to add to a UIScrollView. I only want the view to be 100px high, but when I add it to the scroll view it gets made 460px high, ignoring the frame size I set:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100);
myScrollView.autoresizesSubviews = NO
[myScrollView addSubview:vc.view];
[vc release];
```

I have set the scroll view to not autoresize subviews but it seems this is still happening! What can I do?

I have also tried setting the frame size inside loadView: in the UIViewController (which is where I will add all my controls and will need access to the size of the view) but that doesnt work either!

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100); // still doesnt work
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using loadView incorrectly, im even suprised you see a view (you shouldnt since in load view you arent assigns the vc view to anything),  in loadView you must assign your view to a new UIView i nstance, anyway, you should be doing the same but in viewDidLoad  instead of load view, that might work for you

Comment: Yes I'm seeing a view as the call to [super loadView] creates a plain UIView object. I just don't understand why it's autoresizing the view!

Comment: try doing it in view did load, im not sure exactly what you are doing

Comment: Ah, fixed it now! Really not sure how but it's working! I'm using loadView to setup my views and then viewDidLoad to fill my view with the current data and settings. I believe this is fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of how I do it. Note that the origin is with respect to the view you are adding to (in my case 'self').

```
appRect.origin=CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);// origin
appRect.size = CGSizeMake(320.0f, 100.0f); //size
CGRect frame = CGRectInset(appRect, 0.0f, 0.0f);
gv=[[GraphicsView alloc] initWithFrame:appRect object:[model me]];
[gv setFrame:frame];

[self.view addSubview:gv];
[gv release];
```